# Find $Im(T)$, $Ker(T)$, $Im(T) \cap Ker(T)$ if possible

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $B = \{v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$.
$B$ is unknown and the following matrix is given: $[T]_{B} = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    24 & 14 & 3 \\
    2 & 6 & 17
\end{bmatrix}$

I need to find $Im(T)$, $Ker(T)$, $Im(T) \cap Ker(T)$. If it's not possible I need to explain why.

And the second part of the question is would my answer change if I knew that $B = [1, 1 + x, 1 + x + x^2]$ ?

I don't know how to approach this kind of question so I want to ask for some directions here...

Comment: May be you should first look for determinant.. If it is zero then you are lucky.. Kernel is trivial, Image is full..

Comment: It is not zero...

Comment: @pjs36 Fixed sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ means the space of polynomials of degree less than three (otherwise, it wouldn't be three dimensional). The determinant of $[T]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is not zero and hence $T$ is invertible. Thus, $\operatorname{Im}(T) = \mathbb{R}_3[x]$ and $\ker(T) = \{ 0 \}$ (here, $0$ is the zero polynomial).

Comment: Thank you. What if the matrix was not invertible? Because that's another part of the question where they give me another matrix

Comment: I don't understand - the matrix is invertible!

Comment: Not invertible I meant **

Comment: If the matrix wouldn't be invertible, you wouldn't be able to say what the image is explicitly unless it is trivial ($\{0\}$) - only in terms of the basis elements $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Same for the kernel and the intersection.

Comment: If $B = [1, 1 + x, 1 + x + x^2]$ then it is also not possible?

Comment: If you are given an explicit basis and an explicit matrix, you can all the subspaces explicitly (no matter whether the matrix is invertible or not).